# Why does my computer say " failed to load session" in ( Ubuntu 12.04 )?

Tags: 12.04

I tried a lot of  commands , but nothing works, I can't get my desktop back.

Answer (score 0):

Here how u can fix your problem :

when u boot your ubuntu on login screen :

Open virtual console (tty) by pressing `ctrl+alt+F1` ,

when you enter to console mode :

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

**And Try !**